# Computer based math question IPV4 calculate unique addresses?

Tags: probability, permutations, computer-science

> Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPV4) addresses consist of 32 bits.
>
> In human readable form as composed of 4 8-bit numbers.
>
> How many unique addresses (including zeros) are possible with IPV4?

I have seen online the answer is

$2^{32}$ = 429496296

I am not sure if this is correct I would of though a Permutation calculation should be preformed?

Comment: $8$ bit numbers : $2^8$ in base 10, i.e. numbers from $0$ to $255$. The address consists of any 4 such numbers, i.e. $$256 \times 256 \times 256 \times 256 = 2^8 \times 2^8 \times 2^8 \times 2^8 = 2^{8\times 4} = 2^{32}.$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: @ snar: Great that is what I was looking for a visual representation of what was actually going on behind the power  Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend avoiding thinking in terms of "permutations" and think instead more simply in terms of rule of product.  If I want to count a scenario and I can describe each outcome to the scenario uniquely via a sequence of steps such that the number of options per step does not depend on the choices made in previous steps, then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options multiplied together.  So here, $256$ options for the first 8-bit number, $256$ options for the second, etc... Note that this also explains permutations.  $n$ options for 1st, $n-1$ options for 2nd, ...

Comment: Only after you are familiar enough with permutations to not incorrectly think they should be applied to a problem like this would I go back to using them as a quick shortcut.  It seems like you aren't fully familiar with what sort of objects permutations count or what they describe.